# mysqlslap iterations drop performance

Tags: mysql, performance

I setup some mysqlslap tests and it is giving me weird results, which I don't understand
Here is mysqlslap command:

```
# test reads
mysqlslap --auto-generate-sql \
      --auto-generate-sql-add-autoincrement \
      --auto-generate-sql-load-type=read \
      --auto-generate-sql-secondary-indexes=2 \
      --auto-generate-sql-unique-query-number=30 \
      --auto-generate-sql-unique-write-number=30 \
      --auto-generate-sql-write-number=3000 \
      --csv=/tmp/slap-read.log \
      --debug-info \
      --engine=innodb \
      --iterations=${ITERATION} \
      --number-char-cols=5 \
      --number-int-cols=8 \
      --number-of-queries=1000 \
      --password=${MYSQL_PASS} \
      --port=3306 \
      --user=${MYSQL_USER} \
      --verbose \
      --host=${REMOTE_HOST}
```

I run this command for iteration=1 then 2, 3

I got this results:

```
innodb,read,29.768,29.768,29.768,1,1000
innodb,read,29.111,27.293,30.930,1,1000
innodb,read,162.278,30.826,269.489,1,1000
```

I don't understand why from iteration=3 and upper time to perform test increases so dramatically. CPU usage/memory usage is about few %, also DISK IO is low...

Here is my mysql config:

```
[client]
port = 3306
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysqld_safe]
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice = 0
skip-syslog
[mysqld]
user = mysql
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port = 3306
basedir = /usr
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
innodb_file_per_table
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 512M
thread_stack = 192K
myisam-recover = BACKUP
query_cache_limit = 1M
server-id = 1002
log-error = /var/log/mysql/mysql-error.log
slow_query_log = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 5
expire_logs_days = 7
max_connections = 400
max_connect_errors = 10
table_cache = 2048
sort_buffer_size = 64K
join_buffer_size = 1M
thread_cache_size = 16
query_cache_size = 0
ft_min_word_len = 4
tmp_table_size = 64M
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:100M:autoextend
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3000M
innodb_io_capacity = 1000
innodb_log_file_size = 900M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 300
innodb_thread_concurrency = 1000
innodb_concurrency_tickets = 500
innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0
ssl-ca = /etc/mysql/cert/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert = /etc/mysql/cert/server-cert.pem
ssl-key = /etc/mysql/cert/server-key.pem
event_scheduler = ON
innodb_print_all_deadlock = 1
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog = 1
```

I use Mariadb 10.0 on ubuntu 16.04